# How do you create a new database in SQL Developer?

Tags: oracle-12c

I  am a software developer that supports and develops an application that connects to both Oracle databases and SQL Server databases.  I want to learn more about database administration.

In SQL Studio Manager you can open a connection to a server and then selected the master database and then run a statement like this:

```
CREATE Database TestDatabase
```

TestDatabase is then available to connect to on that database server.

However, with SQL Developer you have to connect to a database already created (rather than connecting to the server).  Therefore how do you create a new database in SQL Developer?

I thought I would be able to find my answer by Googling.  However, this was not the case.  There seem to be hundreds of tutorials about creating tables but I cannot find any about creating a database.

Answer (score 3):

The term `database` has a different meaning in Oracle. The definition of database by Oracle:

> A set of files, located on disk, that store data. Because a database
>   instance and a database are so closely connected, the term Oracle
>   database is often used to refer to both instance and database.

[Oracle Database Architecture](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/intro.htm#CNCPT88788)

If you wanted to seperate data per application, you could do that by using seperate tablespaces and schemas.

Creating such a database is a complex process, and it is done with DBCA or SQL*Plus on the database server, not with a remote connection:

[Creating and Configuring an Oracle Database](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMIN/create.htm#ADMIN002)

In 12c, the multitenant architechture was introduced, that is similar to the concept in SQL Server.

[Overview of Managing a Multitenant Environment](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMIN/cdb_intro.htm#ADMIN13507)

If you have a container database, there you can easily create new pluggable databases from SQL Developer, when using a DBA connection.

[Managing Pluggable Databases (PDBs) using Oracle SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/12c/r1/12c_sqldev/pdb/12cPDB01.html)